# How to log page requests using Apache?

Tags: html, apache, http, logging, timestamp

I am hosting some documents on my local machine using Apache for my group.
I have copied/linked the documents under `/var/www/html`.

Is there a way to log the requests with timestamps for each request?

Answer (score 12):

Logging should already be enabled out of the box, and be logging to a file called access_log. I've never seen an install where it wasn't already turned on.

Usually the directive for where to log to is set in a file called httpd.conf.
Most of the time, the file is in /var/log/apache2.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not able to find these access logs. Any ideas where else to look? [This page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/logs.html#accesslog) doesn't help either.

Comment: @Lazer: Did you take a look at the link covener suggested with each distribution's default http access log directory? What distro are you using?

Comment: `tail -F /var/log/apache2/access.log`

Comment: @AkiraYamamoto Yes, if the location of the access log is in /var/log/apache2, that command will work. But the OP doesn't know that.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your apache server is running and you have shell access:

do this:

```
genja ~ # ps aux |grep apache|tail -n1 
root     23605  0.0  0.2 248636 10684 ?        Ss   Jun08   0:06 /usr/sbin/apache2 -D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D LANGUAGE -D MANUAL -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D PHP5 -D PERL -D PROXY -D SCGI -d /usr/lib64/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -k start
```

.. that is an apache daemon process. You are looking for "-f /etc/apache2/http.conf".
If your apache server was not told (by the distro init scripts) where to get the config file it will look in the default location which could be under: **/etc/apache2/** or **/etc/httpd/** (or anywhere else, really, but those two are most common). In that folder you will find a file called **apache2.conf** or **httpd.conf**
just try this:

```
find /etc/ -iname httpd.conf -o -iname apache2.conf
```

Once you have located the configuration file for the apache server, look for the line where they include the modules configurations. On my system it looks like this:

```
Include /etc/apache2/modules.d/*.conf
```

Now you need to figure out where the log file is:

```
genja modules.d # grep CustomLog /etc/apache2/modules.d/*
00_mod_log_config.conf:# a CustomLog directive (see below).
00_mod_log_config.conf:CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log common
00_mod_log_config.conf:#CustomLog /var/log/apache2/referer_log referer
00_mod_log_config.conf:#CustomLog /var/log/apache2/agent_logs agent
00_mod_log_config.conf:#CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log combined
```

you are looking for: CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log common.
Note that this CustomLog directive could be in the main apache2.conf file too.
 
Now you have the location of the log file. The most likely thing to be stopping your server from logging now is file permissions. Make sure the directory given under CustomLog exists and that the apache server can write to it:

as root:

```
mkdir -p /var/log/apache2
touch /var/log/apache2/access_log
chown -R APACHEUSER /var/log/apache2
chmod 755 /var/log/apache2
chmod 644 /var/apache2/access_log
```

where APACHEUSER is likely to be apache or www or even httpd. You can figure that out by running:

```
genja ~ # ps aux |grep apache |awk '{print $1}'
apache
(...)
apache
root
```

So the user running the apache server on my system is actually called apache. It is not root. Or at least should not be.

restart your server after changing the permission of that file. I dont know how your distro does it. There is a service[s] command on ubuntu I think. But you can always run the init script directly:

/etc/init.d/apache restart (ir may be under a different location on your distro) just reboot the whole computer if you cant figure out how to restart the apache server.

If the access_log file is empty after you restarted the server change APACHEUSER to root in the above command.

after all this just use your favourite pager or text editor to look at the log. Or even tail -f  to monitor it in real time. I hope this helps. gl.

Comment: /usr/local/etc/apache2 is another common location

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine you have set up a virtual host (so called vhost) for your */var/www/html* document root.
So you can just add your log set up requirements within that specific vhost, sothat you'll get a specific log file.

Like this example :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName www.yourdomain.org
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.de

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride all
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            # if you need some users basic authentication
            # AuthType Basic
            # AuthName "MY DOMAIN AUTHENTICATION"
            # AuthUserFile ${APACHE_BASEDIR}/conf.d/special_users
            # Require user foobar
    </Directory>

    # your log specific requirements
    # LOGS (overwriting previous conf See /etc/apache2/apache2.conf)
    # Possible values for LogLevel : debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
    LogLevel info
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/my_special_error.log
    # Option 1 (recommended): you merge these specific logs with the overall log file name and format
    # CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    # Or, Option 2: you set up a specific log file for that domain
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" my_special_access.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/my_special_access.log
</VirtualHost>
```

You will find the way the logs are formatted in the main apache configuration file, eg  */etc/apache2/apache2.conf* in debian's like distros. Or you take them as they are, or you overwrite them in your virtual host configuration. If you are not working with virtual hosts, that does not change much these principles.

Then you can manipulate the *access.log* file to extract, analyze, copy or do whatever you want with this. You can do that either in shell bash scripting (or perl or even python or C or...). I would recommend bash, that you can easily automatized as a cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" mylog
CustomLog logs/doc_root_access_log mylog
```

which will output like below (the timestamp) to the log file doc_root_access_log

```
127.0.0.1 - frank [10/Oct/2000:13:55:36 -0700] "GET /apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326
```

You should really refer [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#accesslog) as they have plenties of explanation especially on the log modifier.